# Hide featured image in single post view

Tags: css

I want to hide featured image on single post view. i tried with plugin and also theme panel have option to hide feature image but it did not work. I also add custom CSS code but did not work for me. Is any other way to hide featured image? Please help me to solve my issue.
I am using Newspaper theme (Version: 11.5.1).
Website: [AmazClub](https://amazclub.com/)

The page I need help with:
https://amazclub.com/airpods-pro-in-the-shower/

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom CSS

```css
.postid-894 .tdb_single_featured_image {
  display: none;
}
```

The `.postid-894` is a class that is applied to the specific post you linked, so the style wont be applied to other posts.

The `.tdb_single_featured_image` is the featured image element.

The `display: none;` will prevent the selected element from rendering in the page.